# (Ida Pro) Find out which functions use the import symbol

Tags: reverse-engineering, ida

I am new to Ida and I need to use it to identify which functions within the executable call one of these. I am trying to find a way a packet is encrypted as a security exercise. Lets say I want to look at the imports window and see these, does that mean that those are the only functions referenced in the executable?
How can I find where sendto is referenced? I tried to search it by name but the search takes forever and does not seem to find anything.

Address  Ordinal Name                                  Library
-------  ------- ----                                  -------
0109150C 111     **imp_WSAGetLastError                 WS2_32

01091524 101     __imp_WSAAsyncSelect                  WS2_32

0109157C         freeaddrinfo                          WS2_32

01091578         getaddrinfo                           WS2_32

01091548 57      __imp_gethostname                     WS2_32

01091518 52      __imp_gethostbyname                   WS2_32

01091530 23      __imp_socket                          WS2_32

01091528 21      __imp_setsockopt                      WS2_32

01091554 20      sendto                                WS2_32

0109154C 19      __imp_send                            WS2_32

01091574 18      __imp_select                          WS2_32

01091558 17      recvfrom                              WS2_32

01091550 16      __imp_recv                            WS2_32

01091508 15      __imp_ntohs                           WS2_32

01091514 14      ntohl                                 WS2_32

01091540 13      __imp_listen                          WS2_32

0109151C 12      __imp_inet_ntoa                       WS2_32

01091520 11      __imp_inet_addr                       WS2_32

01091580 10      __imp_ioctlsocket                     WS2_32

01091568 115     __imp_WSAStartup                      WS2_32

01091538 9       __imp_htons                           WS2_32

01091534 3       __imp_closesocket                     WS2_32

0109152C         WSAIoctl                              WS2_32

01091510 8       htonl                                 WS2_32

01091570 151     __imp**_WSAFDIsSet                    WS2_32
0109155C 7       getsockopt                            WS2_32
0109153C 2       __imp_bind                            WS2_32
01091564 6       getsockname                           WS2_32
01091560 5       getpeername                           WS2_32
01091544 1       __imp_accept                          WS2_32
01091584 4       __imp_connect                         WS2_32
0109156C 116     __imp_WSACleanup                      WS2_32

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to find where the imported function is used, I have in the Import view this `MessageBoxA` function:

```
00406160  MessageBoxA USER32
```

double click on it, it will gets you to the IDA View and you will see something like:

```
.idata:00406160 ; int __stdcall MessageBoxA(HWND hWnd, LPCSTR lpText, LPCSTR lpCaption, UINT uType)
.idata:00406160                 extrn __imp_MessageBoxA:dword ; DATA XREF: MessageBoxA^r
```

click on the function name, `MessageBoxA`, it will becomes yellow, then click <kbd>X</kbd> on the keyboard or right click on the function and then choose **Jump to xref to operand ...**. You will go to where the function is used or you will see dialog box if it's called from more than one place.